# Saiku 3.8 - .saiku files location

Tags: saiku

Actually I'm using the 3.8 version of Saiku and I can't find where the .saiku files are stored. In older versions, those files were stored in folders inside the folders of the backend app, but in this version I can't find them.

Can anybody help me? Please.

Thx in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to do? if you just want the ..saiku file, you can download the .saiku files you save from the Pentaho User Console. Select the file and click Download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are stored in the jackrabbit repository in the installation directory. You can access the content via Webdav as described on the wiki http://wiki.meteorite.bi